# How to create a claw out of this mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting, meta-objects

The mesh on the arms of my reptile are quite complex and I'm wondering what would be good way to make some appendages on this piece. I'd tried sculpting and proportional editing but was not able to make anything that resembles a claw. The mesh was generated using metaballs.

Any tips or info on this procedure?

[image]

Comment: There are a bunch of ways to do this, it is primary opinion based. I will give you an example of how to do it though

Comment: Can you give me an example on what kind of claw you want?

Comment: This is the reference image I'm using, I had no trouble with the body except for the claws on the legs.

Comment: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/19/03/ff/1903ff5b7a5f1a183963d840128613bf.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beginning with a box primitive, I used vertex extrusions, then boolean modifiers to attach the claw to the arm (which will then be attached to the body).

Then I was able to sculpt this using smooth, crease, and clay strips brushes.

[image]

Comment: So technically I used a different mesh..